# php pdo sql query Error : 1064 with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My PDO query is throwing an error

> 42000 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->config->__get('table_medicine')} WHERE patient_id = ? AND medicine LIKE %?%";
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $data = array($patient_id, $medicine);
    $response = $query->execute($data) or die(implode(" ", $query->errorInfo()));
```

Can someone see what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` need to be inside the string argument to `LIKE`. Either use `CONCAT()` in the SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->config->__get('table_medicine')} 
        WHERE patient_id = ? AND medicine LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

or do the concatenation in PHP:

```
$data = array($patient_id, '%'.$medicine.'%');
```